# Не пойму синтаксис следующей строки

Tags: java

Есть некоторый метод, принимающий `String value`, который возвращает следующую строку, смысл которой мне не совсем понятен:

```
return value == null || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
```

Как я понимаю, данный метод возвращает `null` если `value` совпадает с `"null"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта строка возвращает булевое значение. Перепишем словами:

```
value == null || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
```

> `value` равно `null` либо строка "null" равна `value` без учета регистра.

Т.о. метод вернет `true` если `value` принимает значение `null`, `"null"` или `"Null"`.

Чтобы разобраться в выражениях можно расставлять в них скобки:

```
(value==null) || ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
```

либо разбивать на отдельные шаги и проверить что возвращается на каждом шаге:

```
boolean isNull = value==null;
boolean isStringNull = "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value);
return isNull || isStringNull;
```

либо запустить код и экспериментировать с разными значениями `value`